# How to specify user directory when connecting to the Google Cloud Engine instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

When I connect to the same instance from gcloud shell, it would log in as `[user name 1]`, which is the same as my gmail account.
However, when I connect to the same instance from my local laptop, it would log in as `[user name 2]`, which uses my laptop user name as the user name, although my gcloud configuration uses my gmail account.
So if I upload a file from my local laptop, it would be in `home/[user name 2]` instead of `home/[user name 1]`.
Does anyone know how to specify the user when logging into an instance? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Cloud Shell uses the User Identity that you logged into the Google Cloud Console with and not the identity configured by the CLI (gcloud). The web browser does not know about or have access to the CLI configuration. The CLI does not even need to be installed to use Cloud Shell from the browser.

> Does anyone know how to specify the user when logging into an
>   instance? Thank you.

Log into the Google Cloud Console with the credentials that you want to use inside Cloud Shell.

Comment: The [user name 1]  of the Google Cloud Shell uses the gmail account. The [user name 2] is my laptop. I do want to log into the instance using the same [user name 1] from my laptop. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Just login. Open a new browser (I use Chrome) on the right-hand side of a new window you should see something like "Gmail Images your_initials". Click on your initialize (the Google Accounts Login Button) and log out of your current account and login with your designed account. You can also go to https://accounts.google.com

Comment: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/5-tips-for-managing-multiple-google-accounts/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `scp` to transfer the file instead of gcloud command.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#scp

I also wrote a shell script `gcp.sh` to facilitate it.

```sh
for file in "$@"
do
    scp -i ~/.ssh/<your key file> "$file" <your user name>@<your instance ip>:~/
done
```

It worked!